# Error while trying to analyse Java project code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I configured the Eclipse Sonar Plugin to point to my SonarQube server, and it was ok. My Sonar Qube Server version is 3.7.4. I followed [this page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)

I'm getting this error below while trying to run Sonar analysis via Sonar Eclipse Plugin. Can anyone help me?

I have the  tag configured properly in my pom.xml file:

```
        <scm>    
<connection>scm:svn:https://svnjiracloud.cit.com.br/repos/svn/PAPS/trunk/Fontes/PortalRAM/faturamento-auditorias-batch</connection>
          <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svnjiracloud.cit.com.br/repos/svn/PAPS/trunk/Fontes/PortalRAM/faturamento-auditorias-batch</developerConnection>
          <url>https://svnjiracloud.cit.com.br/repos/svn/PAPS/trunk/Fontes/PortalRAM/faturamento-auditorias-batch</url>
        </scm>

        Error:
    15:36:05.138 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3 done: 3865 ms
    15:36:05.161 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor done: 3893 ms
    15:36:05.161 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.scmstats.ScmStatsSensor@526018e0...
    Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
    Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: SCM URL must not be blank. Please check the parameter SCM URL or the <scm> section of Maven pom.
        at org.sonar.plugins.scmstats.UrlChecker.failure(UrlChecker.java:56)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scmstats.UrlChecker.check(UrlChecker.java:36)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scmstats.ScmStatsSensor.analyse(ScmStatsSensor.java:53)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:114)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:187)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:182)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:175)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The [source code from the `org.sonar.stats.plugin`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins/sonar-scm-stats-plugin/0.1/org/sonar/plugins/scmstats/UrlChecker.java#30) clearly states that you are providing a blank URL for you SCM section., so it seems quite weird since you reported that the related section was filled. Maybe an issue on the *Sonar Maven Plugins* so try browsing the [Issues Tracker](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS).

I think that disabling the *Sonar SCM Stats Plugin* should get you out of this issue, so try it if it is an eligible solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem updating the **Scm Stats [scmstats]** SonarQube server plugin version from **0.1** to **0.3.1**

Thanks guys.